# scraping amazon web using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am using R to scrape amazon web for getting the prices of the products.
The products exist in 5 pages so each time i should enter different url.
that is the code which i used:

```
pages<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
##getting the url of the 5 pages
urls<-rbindlist(lapply(pages,function(x){
  url<-paste("https://www.amazon.co.uk/Best-Sellers-Health-Personal-Care-Weight-Loss-Supplements/zgbs/drugstore/2826476031#",x,sep="")
  data.frame(url)
}),fill=TRUE)


product.price<-rbindlist(apply(urls,1,function(url){
  locations <- url %>%
    map(read_html) %>%
    map(html_nodes, xpath = '//*[@id="zg_centerListWrapper"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[1]/span') %>%
    map(html_text) %>%
    simplify()
  data.frame(locations)
}),fill=TRUE)
```

There are 100 product, 20 in each page, and what i am getting is the first 20 repeated 5 times.
It means that i entered only the first url.
how can i get an access to all of the pages?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Best-Sellers-Health-Personal-Care-Weight-Loss-Supplements/zgbs/drugstore/2826476031#'

page <- read_html(url)

numPages <- page %>%
  html_node('.zg_pagination') %>%
  html_nodes('li') %>%
  length

items <- vector()
for(i in 1:numPages){
  url <- paste0(url, i)
  page <- read_html(url)

  item <- page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="zg_centerListWrapper"]/div/div[2]/div/a/div[2]') %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE)

  items <- append(items, item)
}
```

Main differences:

1. I went with a loop instead of a functional approach
2. Modified the xpath argument to get the item name - you could easily extend to get price, stars, etc.